# Pilot feature questions - Is SSE the best place for that?

Tags: discussion

I have reservations about people using SFSE for troubleshooting pilot features as in this question here:

[Implementing External data source and External objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/implementing-external-data-source-and-external-objects)

1. There are very few other community members who will be likely to be able to help
2. The features are likely to change, sometimes drastically, by the time they go into GA reducing the long-term effectiveness of using SFSE as an ongoing knowledge base for such questions

Thoughts?

Comment: What is SSE? do you mean : SFSE?

Comment: Sales Support Engineer?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think its appropriate for us to stop members from asking their questions. Its simply a case as you say where no one here will likely be able to provide answers that will be helpful. If members here are part of the kind of beta programs that I've been involved in with other companies, NDA's will presumably prevent them from responding. I'm inclined to say it's a problem that doesn't need solving.

Just as features of SF change from release to release, some of the answers to questions that have already been asked here are no longer completely accurate or valid. That's going to happen with any question that gets asked.

Comment: Agreed, as it stands stuff changes pretty dramatically from release to release and stale answers are going to happen regardless of whether it's a pilot feature or not ...

Comment: +1 & Thats why we as community can edit answers.

Comment: @Samuel - While it's true we can edit pages, your comment assumes we edit pages *before* someone visits them to read out-dated/erroneous & answers that no longer applies to them. That's going to happen regardless of what content we allow for discussion. Just look at how rapidly info related to communities has changed since they've been released!

Comment: Too bad there is no good way to tie an answer to a sf release version. We could do tags though and add them to answers that are likely to change so it ties the answer to say a "Winter 17" tag. not sure if it would be useful or not but I digress

Comment: @Eric Valid point. The problem is that no one knows when a feature will be deprecated at the time the question is *asked and answered*. I know my crystal ball doesn't work well enough to predict those things. As an example, who knew 3 months ago that there'd be a reprieve given in SU17 on enforcement of the Locker Service?